# Laravel 5.2 query scopes unexpected behavior with orWhere

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I use a query scope that should append a orWhere condition but it appends a normal where (with AND). If I remove the query scope and put it directly it does return the OR condition.

The query looks like this:

```
$query = MyModel::firstQueryScope()->secondQueryScope();
```

FirstQueryScope:

```
public function scopeFirstQueryScope($query){
    return $query->where('someAttribute', 0);
}
```

Second Query Scope:

```
public function scopeSecondQueryScope($query){
    return $query->orWhere('someOtherAttribute', 0);
}
```

Building the query this way should be the same as:

```
$query = MyModel::where('someAttribute', 0)->orWhere('someOtherAttribute', 0);
```

But the first approach returns this query:

- `select * from MyModelTable where someAttribute = 0 AND (someOtherAttribute = 0)`.

The second approach returns:

- `select * from MyModelTable where someAttribute = 0 OR someOtherAttribute = 0`

I've have notice two things:

1. No matter in what order you call FirstQueryScope or SecondQueryScope, it always surrounds the **orWhere** scope with parenthesis.
2. The **orWhere** method only ads the parenthesis when called from the query scope.

What am I doing wrong? or can this be an Eloquent's bug?

Note: the query that I'm building is more elaborated but I've break it down to this simplicity to verify that I'm not doing anything strange.

### Update

I try to debug Eloquent's building process and found that it is adding a **nested where** and inside it the *orWhere* scope. Again this only happens when putting the *orWhere* inside an scope but does not happen when adding a simple *where*. The **nested where** is the responsable for surrounding the *orWhere* expression within parenthisis.

Comment: in case someone reaches here: https://techsemicolon.github.io/blog/2019/03/17/laravel-finally-has-higher-level-or-where/

Answer (score 1):

I think scopes are isolated by itself.

Simply add a third scope.

```
public function scopeFirstQueryOrSecondQuery($query){
    return $query->where('someAttribute', 0)
        ->orWhere('someOtherAttribute', 0);
}
```

-

```
MyModel::firstQueryOrSecondQuery()->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that but I'll be duplicating my code. What do you mean scopes are isolated? As long as I know they should not change the query builder scopes. Furthermore, this happens only when adding a **orWhere** to the scope. For some reason Eloquent is adding a NestedWhere but I hadn't been able to track its origin.